# What is font in Tesseract folder eurotext.tif

Tags: ocr, tesseract

What is the font used in sample image file Tesseract (eurotext.tif) ?
[image: eurotext.tif]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below helps.

1. Crop 4-10 characters in a line similar to below.
   [image]
2. Upload the cropped image to this website [What Font Is](http://www.whatfontis.com/) .
3. Follow the instructions to type in the separated `F` `u` `c` `h` `s` letters of your image to help the website to detect the font.
4. Click continue to get recognized font result. Below is the first two  output.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks thewaywewere, but not the same font

Comment: It output many fonts. The `1` is with highest confidence, similar to `tesseract`. You may go to  surf the site and check.

Answer (score 0):

How about Aboriginal Serif Bold?

[Aboriginal Serif Bold](http://www.fonts2u.com/aboriginal-serif-bold.font?ptext=Fuchs%20springt&submit=Submit)

[image]